# Error Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I have a login page that I'm trying to redirect to the home page with Reactjs. I'm using `this.props.history.push("/")` to redirect the page, but I get an error on the console saying :

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I attached my login page below .

Does someone know what am I doing and help with that?

```js
import React from 'react';
import './LoginPage.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'test',
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  login = () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    //send a login request
    axios('/login/signin', {
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        //store the token in my pocket
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        this.props.history.push('/');
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="text-center">
          <input
            className="login-input mb-4 mt-4"
            placeholder="Email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            name="email"
            type="text"
          />
          <br></br>

          <input
            className="login-input"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            name="password"
            type="password"
          />
          <br></br>

          <div className="login-button-container">
            <button className="mt-4 button-input" onClick={this.login}>
              Sign in
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

I have added my App.js page, do I need to add something on Login Route to render the history push?

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Alert />

          <Header />
          <NavBar />

          <Kommunicate />

          <Switch>
            <Route path="/shop">
              <Shop />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/register">
              <RegisterPage />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/login">
              <LoginPage />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/about">
              <About />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/customer">
              <CustomerSupport />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/feedback">
              <Feedback />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/policies">
              <Policies />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/settings">
              <Settings />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/purchases">
              <Purchases />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/delivery">
              <Delivery />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/profile">
              <Profile />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/favourite">
              <Favourite />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/cart">
              <Cart />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
          </Switch>

          <Newsletter />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It seems that your Login page is not getting `props.history`. Can you post code of the parent component that renders Login page please?

Comment: I just added my App.js page that renders the Login, do I need to add something on the login route to render the history push

Comment: Nice. I will add my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need to do is add `props` from `Route` component's `component` property to your `LoginPage`:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Alert />

          <Header />
          <NavBar />

          <Kommunicate />

          <Switch>
            ...
            <Route path="/login" component={(props) => <LoginPage  {...props} />}/>
            ...
          </Switch>

          <Newsletter />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

In this way you are passing some of the Router properties that it gives you, alongside `history` and other ones.

Comment: Glad i helped. Cheers